# ERC20 Token successfully deploy without owner

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, erc20

I have deployed my ERC20 token contract onto the Rospten network, when I checked on the Etherscan and I can't see my account appear in the Holder list. Why is that ?

> 0x88BAcDE95d741729aaF399e75ac14dB971f72f30

Please advise

[image: Snapshot]

[ERC20 Token source code](https://github.com/davidbongcc/ERC20)

Comment: If you can copy-paste the contract address, I can write details on how to mint, if you need.

Comment: @ferit- I've shared the ERC20 token address above. Please show me how to mint. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etherscan determines token balances by watching for the `Transfer` event. In your constructor function:

```
constructor()
    public
{
    totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
}
```

you are assigning the `totalSupply_` to `msg.sender`'s balance, but without emitting an event Etherscan is unaware of this.

The typical way to handle a token minting event is to show the transfer as originating from `0x00`. Add the following line to the constructor and the balance should display properly on Etherescan and other block explorers.

```
emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalSupply_);
```

Answer (score 1):

Deploying an ERC20 contract doesn't make your address a holder of the token.

You can `mint` tokens to your account though, as you are the owner of the contract.

Comment: 0x88BAcDE95d741729aaF399e75ac14dB971f72f30

Comment: This contract doesn't seem to have a mint function. Can you please share the source code?

Comment: @ferit- I tried to share my code but StackOverflow doesn't allow. It complaints only code and need more comments, how can I share the code with you here?

Comment: You can upload it somewhere and pass the link.

Comment: Please see the link that I shared above (ERC20 source code).

Answer (score 1):

When you create an ERC20 token you need to mint the tokens and move them to one address or a list of addresses.

If you don't want to hard-code any addresses in the contract you can send all the tokens to the deployer address as per [this guide](https://p2pmoon.com/erc20-token-explained/) for example. Then you can use that account to distribute your tokens however you want.

If you want to see the initial owner then you can do that by adding this to your ERC20 constructor.

```
contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    address public admin;

    constructor() ERC20("dust", "P2PM") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10 ** decimals());
        admin = msg.sender; // Sets admin address in blockchain
    }
}
```

Unless you need to make use of this address, however, there is no need to have it public. You can always move tokens from admin address to anyone you want as long as the transaction is signed with admin's key.